# How to share String among multiple modules?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, user-agent

I have 3 modules: `mod1`, `mod2` and `mod3`. Module `mod1` has dependencies `mod2` and `mod3`.

I want to have one String (in particular it will be UserAgent because all 3 modules HTTP-talk to some server and all 3 should have the same user agent set) to be shared among those 3 modules.

Comment: Are `mod1`, `mod2` and `mod3` gradle modules or just isolated parts of the same app?

Comment: By "gradle modules" you mean library dependency (taken from maven repo)? No, they are module dependency (probably what you call "just isolated parts of the same app")

Comment: What comes to my ming on first glimpse is creating a library module and having `mod1`, `mod2` and `mod3` depend on it. It might be overkill though, considering you only wish to share a single string.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch, what do you think about my solution?

Comment: I think it's the best from what I have so far.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch, did you find better solution for this issue? I am facing with variables sharing across the modules problem, and maybe there is better solution, than I provided. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to make a public class with methods to write and read information.

```
    public static String readnote(Context context, String str) {
    if (context == null) throw new RuntimeException ("Context is null");
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("somenameyouchoose", 0);
    String mycontent = sp.getString(str);
    return mycontent;
}

public static String writenote(Context context, String str) {
    if (context == null) throw new RuntimeException ("Context is null");
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("somenameyouchoose", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString(str);
    editor.commit();
    return str;
}
```

Then you can writenote (this, "myUserAgent") and readnote (this, "myUserAgent").

If you use intent, another aproach is to use intent.putExtra.

Comment: @Marian please check as correct the answer you think it was more helpful in order to help you solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If this "one String" you want to make common for all other modules, is in a `strings.xml` file(not a `String` value in a `.java` file), then you can create a common module say, `mode0`, including your `String` values you want to make common for other modules in it's `strings.xml` file. Then you can add `mode0` as a dependency to other modules. This maybe not the best way to do this but, hope this will be useful!

Answer (score 0):

Add build config field to your subprojects entry of top level build file.

It will be something like this:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android.defaultConfig {
                buildConfigField 'String', 'USER_AGENT', "\"Android-agent\""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `BuildConfig` files of each module you will see:

```
public static final String USER_AGENT = "Android-agent";
```

P.S. Maybe it isn't the best implementation of android subproject detection, but the best one I know